# Cannot call the first element of a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I'm trying to access the first object from `data[]`. Then, grab the keys using `Object.keys()` but it gives me this error:

> "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

I need the output to be an array of the keys.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CodecChart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: [],
      isLoaded: false,

    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    fetch(url)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(post => {this.setState({ post: post })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const data = this.state.post;

// cannot reach the first object of data[]
    var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);


    return (
      <div>

//output should be an array of the keys
        <h5>{keys}</h5>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CodecChart;
```

Comment: it means `data[0]` is undefined - there is no such thing as a JSON object

Answer (score 1):

The first time you try to access `data[0]`, it's still empty:

```
this.state = {
  post: [],
  isLoaded: false,
}
```

and `const data = this.state.post;` means that `data[0]` is undefined.

it's only after the component is mounted, and the state is set correctly that `data[0]` is defined (or not, depending on what the API returns).

Comment: but did you get it to run?

Answer (score -1):

I found a way for it to work by adding another "then" so it can set the "keys" state right after the "posts" state was set. But I wonder if there is another way to make it more elegant. Thank you for trying to help.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      keys: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    fetch(url)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({ posts: posts })
      })
      .then(_ => { this.setState({ keys: Object.keys(this.state.posts[0]) }) })
  }

  render() {
    const keys = this.state.keys;

    return (
      <div>
        <h5>{keys}</h5>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Those isn't how setState works--just handle the case odd not having the data yet.